# Cassandra schema, query

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I'm designing a new application, which will use Cassandra (I'm new in Cassandra). This database will contain only 2-4 column families. The problem is that, I have to provide opportunity to filter based on almost every column attributes. Could you give me some helpful suggestion that I have to keep in mind during planning? What about data redundancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra isn't optimized for this use-case. The preferred way to query data is using the primary key.

Filtering by arbitrary columns is possible

- using the [ALLOW FILTERING](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) query modifier
- creating a [secondary index](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77) for each column, which could not be combined in a single query
- creating lookup tables with different primary key variants based on the column you want to filter

All of those options have their limitations.